# Relative path in AJAX doesn't work for an API

Tags: html, json, ajax, api

I have a server with an API and a website (the client of the API)

It works without any problem when I know the IP of the server and I write the IP in XMLHTTPrequest:

`var url = "http://192.168.0.14/api"`

As my IP is not static, I want a code that works with any IP so I did

` var url = "http://localhost/api" (the server also serve the website)

But when I do that, I get Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

CORS is allowed in response from the server.

Any idea why this happen ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `localhost` does not resolve to the IP `192.168.0.14`, and not HTTP server is listening on whatever IP `localhost` *does* resolve to (which will probably be `127.0.0.1` or `::1`).

Keep in mind that `localhost` means "The computer the browser is running on". It isn't relative to the server the HTML document the JS runs in is. `http://localhost/` is an **absolute** URL, not a relative path.

A relative path would be something like `api`, while an absolute path would be `/api` (which would be relative to the root of the server the HTML document is hosted on).

Comment: But if I don't write http:// , the server will try to find something in the root of the file system... ? What can I do ?

Comment: It will only look in the root of the file system if the URL of the HTML document is a `file:` scheme URL. There is no way to write a relative URL from a `file:` scheme URL to an `http:` scheme URL.

Comment: So how can I do please ?

Comment: @Vesp8266 — As I said, use a URL starting `/api` (assuming I've correctly interpreted your description of the two URLs since you haven't given a complete set of examples).